# parse_url() problem when one of parameters is url

Tags: php, url, uri, parse-url

I call a php script `http://site.com/process.php` that takes a url as one of its parameters. `for=`

```
http://site.com/process.php?for=http://www.anotherwebsite.com
```

I then do this and try to `parse_url()` but parse_url() gives a parse error.

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // /process.php?for=http://www.anotherwebsite.com
parse_url($uri);
```

How can I encode the `for` parameter either on the sending side (in the url) or on the receiving side (php) so that `parse_url()` understands that it's just a parameter that happens to look like a url?

Comment: You need to URL encode the query string values.

Comment: What does `$_GET['for']` give you? Is it the `for` parameter you 're interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first you must `urlencode()` the `for=` parameter, then in `process.php`, you can simply do

```
$url = $_GET["for"];
$url = urldecode($url); // http://www.anotherwebsite.com
```

Here are the functions:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: I think the urldecode() is not useful, OP might just have to use parse_url() on $_GET["url"].

Comment: Well, it works for me :
$url = urlencode("http://www.example.com"); // http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com
print urldecode($url); // http://www.example.com

Answer (score 3):

**Before including your url as a `get` parameter, use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)**

```
$full_url = 'http://site.com/process.php?for=' . urlencode('http://www.anotherwebsite.com');
```

> This function is convenient when
>   encoding a string to be used in a
>   query part of a URL, as a convenient
>   way to pass variables to the next
>   page.

---

To reverse the result of `urlencode`, use [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php). As mario pointed out in a comment below, `$_GET` parameters are already urldecoded.

Comment: Learn something new everyday, thanks @mario :) Edited my answer with your information.